# Rendering polymorphic object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For people that only want the question, here it is :

***Is there a way to specify the folder to look in when you call `render` on an object? I don't want to specify the view, only the folder to look in.***

And for people that want context :

I am working on an activity stream system (something that looks like google+/facebook).

I have "Activities", which are exactly like google+ feeds (or facebook, or whatever!). So, I have a simple loop that display each activities, which are bound to one of the following object (polymorphic) : User, Group, Comment, Note.

In my view that render an activity (`views/activities/_activity.html.erb`), I have

```
<%= render activity.object %>
```

where `activity.object` is a reference to the bound object (User, Group, Note, Comment). If it's a user, it goes to `views/users/_user.html.erb` and renders it. For a group, `views/groups/_group.html.erb`.

That works just fine. However, I come to the point where the rendering of a group in my activities should not be the same rendering as in the group list page. Is there a way to specify the folder to look in when you call `render` on an object? So that my :

```
<%= render activity.object %>
```

would become :

```
<%= render activity.object, :folder => 'views/activities/' %>
```

Note that I don't want to specify which view directly, as I don't want to do a case for each of the possible types of objects (User, Group, Note, Comment) in the activity. I want to to have the same behaviour as of right now, which means if it finds a `views/activities/_user.html.erb`, it would load any user in the activities with that view instead of the one in the `views/users/_user.html.erb`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any folder type option, but when I do this I usually do:

```
<%= render "activities/#{activity.object.class.name.underscore}" %>
```

That would give you similar behaviour.

**EDIT** A good point below by Dominic, if your classes are nested in namespaces, you will have to include the appropriate structure.

i.e.

```
 module Foo
   class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
   end
 end

 # class.name is Foo::Bar, underscored is 'foo/bar'

 <%= render "activities/#{activity.object_type.underscore}" %>
 # will be in
 activities/foo/_bar.html
```

Comment: You could also do "activities/#{activity.object_type.underscore}" to avoid the lookup

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking to do as a workaround... but it's not really efficient, you have to do more work with the activity.object_type or class.name since it also gives you the namespace. It's not really a clean solution in my opinion. Nevertheless, if no other answers come, i'll mark your answer as the right one. Thanks!

Comment: Dominic, good point on the namespace. I think your best bet here would be to continue using the approach above (may as well go with `object_type`) and follow the Rails convention of underscore.  If a namespace exists, it will expect a folder with that name. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Dominic, just realized you were the OP; sorry.  I'm not sure of any other approaches to this, I've used this solution before and it's worked well for me but in the cases I used it, I didn't have namespaces on those models.  If you don't mind the extra folder structure, I'd recommend this; otherwise, you'd have to parse the class name manually.

Comment: Thanks again. FYI, the views are already in /foo/activities, so it makes it to /foo/activities/foo/_bar.html.

Answer (score 2):

In current Rails (3.2.9), you can define a `to_partial_path` method on your model to tell it where to look.

For example, you can do:

```
class User
  def to_partial_path; "user"; end
end
```

Rails will then look for _user.html.erb relative to the view from which you're calling render.

Answer (score 0):

My own approach, which I extracted in [polymorphic_render gem](https://github.com/Mik-die/polymorphic_render) - to add suffixes for special partials, but store that partial in resource folders.

In your case `views/users/_user.html.erb` will have very common user representation (which probably used in users list rendering), but `views/users/_user_activity.html.erb` will render special partial for user activity.

And inserting that partials is very simple, just `<%= polymorphic_render activity.object, :activity %>`